# GPS stops retrieving recent updates

Tags: android, gps, location, google-play-services, android-fusedlocation

I'm having a problem with a few users that their gps tracking app stops updating their position, and keeps sending old position to our backend.

The implementation was based on FusedLocation tutorials, and it works. It is just that, with a few people, it suddenly stops working.

Not sure if it's related, but what happens if I try to get a position while the last try is still trying to get (with the gps icon still blinking)?

The only hint I know is that when I disconnect and connect again to the GoogleApiClient, the gps works fine again. Does anyone also know anything that might be causing it?

I'm using *Play Services: 7.5.0*

Edit: The interval between each gps request is 30 seconds.

Comment: on gps with 3g OR wifi network to get your job done, but should have good signal area coverage in device.

Comment: I don't think this is signal related... the users move around the city, so it is probable that they will go in such areas with low signal. But the problem is  when they go somewhere else, because the app says they remained in the same place as before (with a frozen location).

Comment: Check how often you request a new GPS location, both in terms of minimum time and distance.

Comment: Distance is not a constant.
The time interval is 30 seconds.

Comment: It's just a guess, but is it possible that on some devices Android may be entering Doze / Standby mode? I had similar problem and I had to implement the FusedLocation on an Foreground Service to make it work.